public key recovery failed intermittently with go-ethereum
I am trying to recover public key from signature and digest. below is my code. It's failing sometimes with error recovery failed
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "strings"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/signer/core/apitypes"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        testPublicKeyRecovery(i)
    }
}

func testPublicKeyRecovery(id int) {
    var (
        testToAddress   = common.NewMixedcaseAddress(common.HexToAddress("0xfE14EacC63c56Aa0cd23978D4C3520902CB04AF6"))
        testPolygonArgs = &apitypes.SendTxArgs{
            To:                   &testToAddress,
            Gas:                  hexutil.Uint64(21000),
            MaxFeePerGas:         (*hexutil.Big)(big.NewInt(2000000000)),
            MaxPriorityFeePerGas: (*hexutil.Big)(big.NewInt(1000000000)),
            Value:                (hexutil.Big)(*big.NewInt(1)),
            Nonce:                hexutil.Uint64(0),
            ChainID:              (*hexutil.Big)(new(big.Int).SetUint64(5)),
        }

        testPrivKeyHex = "1692ec3be51c194e969aa3c8ce68ed9769f98dd050005b373940c8f858180b95"
        testPrivKey, _ = crypto.HexToECDSA(testPrivKeyHex)
        testAddress    = crypto.PubkeyToAddress(testPrivKey.PublicKey)

        polygonSigner = types.LatestSignerForChainID(new(big.Int).SetUint64(5))
    )

    messageToSign := func() []byte {
        return polygonSigner.
            Hash(testPolygonArgs.ToTransaction()).
            Bytes()
    }
    signerAddress := strings.ToLower(testAddress.Hex())
    asn1Sig := func() []byte {
        msg := polygonSigner.
            Hash(testPolygonArgs.ToTransaction()).
            Bytes()
        asn1Sig, err := ecdsa.SignASN1(rand.Reader, testPrivKey, msg)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        return asn1Sig
    }
    _, err := RecoverSignatureFromASN1(
        messageToSign(),
        signerAddress,
        asn1Sig(),
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(id, err)
    }
}

var (
    // max value on the curve
    secp256k1N, _ = new(big.Int).SetString("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141", 16)
    // half of the curve
    secp256k1HalfN = new(big.Int).Div(secp256k1N, big.NewInt(2))
)

func RecoverSignatureFromASN1(
    messageToSign []byte,
    signerAddress string,
    asn1Sig []byte,
) (string, error) {
    var params struct{ R, S *big.Int }
    _, err := asn1.Unmarshal(asn1Sig, &params)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal asn1 signature: %w", err)
    }

    // Because of EIP-2 not all elliptic curve signatures are accepted
    // the value of s needs to be SMALLER than half of the curve
    // i.e. we need to flip s if it's greater than half of the curve
    // if s is less than half of the curve, we're on the "good" side of the curve, we can just return
    if params.S.Cmp(secp256k1HalfN) > 0 {
        params.S = new(big.Int).Sub(secp256k1N, params.S)
    }

    sig := make([]byte, crypto.SignatureLength)
    // r value
    copy(sig[:32], params.R.Bytes())
    // s value
    copy(sig[32:64], params.S.Bytes())
    var publicKey []byte
    for _, v := range []int{0, 1, 2, 3} {
        // set v value at the end of sig
        sig[len(sig)-1] = byte(v)
        publicKey, err = secp256k1.RecoverPubkey(messageToSign, sig)
        if err == nil {
            return hexutil.Encode(publicKey), nil
        }
    }

    return "", err
}



What's the question?

@ismael why is it failing sometimes with error recovery failed and most of the time it's working?
